# Is it possible to update `store` value of the mapping of an existing field in ElasticSearch 6.x index?

Tags: elasticsearch, highlight

I have an index created by ElasticSearch 6.8.7. I query against some fields which don't correspond to document's fields, because they are merged copies of document's ones. At index creation their `store` value was set to `false`. Now I need to get highlights, but the query fields content is not stored. Can I update mapping and set `store` to `true`? Index's `_source` is enabled.
[The docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-mapping.html) don't mention this ability, and I can't try to update `store` on my production cluster.

Comment: based on https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-store.html the store is used to store values separately .. I am not sure if it has an impact on highlight .. Can you share an example here ?

Comment: @SahilGupta Storing content has a direct impact on the highlight feature - ES can build a snippet from the field content.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not.

> In general, the mapping for existing fields cannot be updated. There
> are some exceptions to this rule. For instance:
>
> - new properties can be added to Object datatype fields.
> - new multi-fields can be added to existing fields.
> - the ignore_above parameter can be updated.

[Source](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/indices-put-mapping.html).

Also, I tried to update mapping on a sample index, and ES didn't allow me to update `store` value of an existing field.
That is understandable, but still sad.